# Taking a URL and adding /?var0=val0&var1=val1 with out leaving the page and no user input

Tags: php, html

OK - Thanks for taking the time!

I am using WP on a CentOS 6 server. I have a plug in with the functions, I have a function that makes a DB call and populates relevant products based on $_GET  variables, I took from one of the other project and modify it so it works! But here where I run in to the problem, I go to the main page and i have a function that gets called first, goes through the URL name and determines the categories id and then from that I need to pass that to the URL so that when the next function then calls $_GET["category_id"] and that ID  is there and ready to be use and it it does its magic. (all staying on the same page no refreshing or anything)

So I need to put that on the URL as the page is being loaded and so that I can use it (Again i get the variables from a function that is doing all the work with the address for relevant info,) So how do i do it? HTML or PHP, and a straight forward way no extra installs would be nice :)

Edit 1:
So is there something then I could integrate in that would be simple and straight forward that would allow me to do a mini refresh and get the right variables in place, never used JavaScript but seams to be getting or something in php ... Ideas are welcome :)

Comment: you can't change the url in the address bar without redirecting. or add the parameters to all the links leading away from the page so they're added when the user clicks on something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can with javascript and the history API

The only way you can change the url without actually redirecting the user is by using the [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) method.

e.g. open a console and copy and paste this:

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "changes url to stackoverflow.com/yes-you-can", "/yes-you-can");
```

You won't be redirected, and the url of your browser will change [unless, basically, you're using IE 9 or less](http://caniuse.com/#search=pushState). You can see a demo of this on [html5demos.com](http://html5demos.com/history)

Answer (score 0):

OK here is how I am going to get around this problem I am having

I made a new table in the DB and then I already have a list of the Domain We are using, so then I am going to give to the customer there are three columns and they will manually enter the fields and it will be on them to manage and change what they want displayed on the webpage.

CVS import and then BAM! done! just pull $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] and then compare that to the domain column and done! (I will have what ever cat's and sizes they want and it will not be on us to create any complicated functions and if statements for exceptions and it is in there hands!)

Not the exact answer I wanted to get but much easier and not so much complicated :)